# Convert all images into base64 in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular8, base64url

Assume that we are using angular-cli in an Angular 8 application.
Is there a proper way to make ng build to convert all the images (which are mentioned in css, eg. `background: url(/assets/myPic.png)` ) into base64 string?

AFAIK the problem is that Angular 8 is using file-loader instead of url-loader.

I've tried to extend the webpack config using extra-webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = (config, options) => {

    // ... 

    config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: false
                }
            },
        ],
    });

    //...

    return config;
};
```

But somehow this didn't work.

Actually it would be nice if there was an option for this in angular.json

Comment: even better if the image path would be replaced by a content hash, so changes in the image would be recognised by the browser.

Comment: I thought Angular inlines all images from the assets folder in SASS. There are issues on GitHub of people complaining that they can't turn it off.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8945

Comment: "Inlining has been completely removed in the upcoming 7.0. As indicated, considering caching and with the advent of HTTP/2.0 inlining is no longer needed."
And I'm asking Angular 8. Also I have different reason to have them inlined.

Comment: You can use postcss exactly this plugin [postcss-image-inliner](https://github.com/bezoerb/postcss-image-inliner)